# AWS Lambda executes for 15-20 seconds for sending telemetry events to Azure Application Insights

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, azure-application-insights, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a requirement of sending logs from a cloud watch log group to an Application Insights instance as and when it gets logged to the log group. I am trying to do this by adding a cloud watch log group as a trigger for my Lambda and inside my Lambda I am using the application insights library to sent the event to an AI instance.

When the default execution timeout for my lambda is 3 seconds, I am not able to see any logs inside my AI instance My lambda executes successfully and terminates in 2-3 seconds. When I increase the timeout to 20 seconds I can see the logs getting populated in AI and my lambda executed for 15-17 seconds.

My understanding is that AI telemetry client sends the data in batches and store it temporarily on the disk till it is sent. As resources for lambda are getting decommissioned post its execution, I might be losing those events as they might not have been pushed out yet.

How do I ensure that AI telemetry client does not not batch these events and send them as soon as it receives them?

Below is my Lambda code

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var zlib = require("zlib");
    var appInsights = require("applicationinsights");

    appInsights.setup("<My Subscription Key>").setUseDiskRetryCaching(false);;
    var client = appInsights.defaultClient;
    // TODO implement
    var payload = new Buffer.from(event.awslogs.data, 'base64');

    zlib.gunzip(payload, function(err, dezipped) {
        if (!err) {
            client.trackEvent({ name: dezipped.toString() });
        }
    });

    client.flush(); 
};
```

Any other approach or best practice that I should follow to achieve my goal?

Comment: I also face this issue when using `ElastiCache` in my lambda. 
I Got solution is by closing `ElastiCache` connection.
As I don't know about `Azure` but something similar happen.

Comment: If you need code I can provide.

Comment: @IftekharDani For application insights we do not manage opening or closing connection. All of that is taken care by the library itself. I am not sure how or if we could do that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see this behavior, only when my lambda is executed after a gap of a few minutes after its previous invocation. I tried running the lambda continuously at a interval of 1 sec and I could see that only the first request takes that much amount of time and the subsequent requests take not more than 400 milliseconds on an average. This is because for the first lambda execution request AWS takes some time to commission resources and uses the same resources if the lambda is called in quick succession post the first call.

Looks like my understanding "resources for lambda are get decommissioned post its execution" was incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing,

```
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
```

in your code.

Please add this after the immediate entry to the function and also invoke callback with a response to exit the process.

Modified code is:

```
    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    var zlib = require("zlib");
    var appInsights = require("applicationinsights");

    appInsights.setup("<My Subscription Key>").setUseDiskRetryCaching(false);;
    var client = appInsights.defaultClient;
    // TODO implement
    var payload = new Buffer.from(event.awslogs.data, 'base64');

    function gunzipcomplete() { 
         client.flush();
         callback(null, done);
    }

    zlib.gunzip(payload, function(err, dezipped) {
        if (!err) {
            client.trackEvent({ name: dezipped.toString() });
        }
        gunzipcomplete();  // this is a complete.
    });



};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please look this article `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html` . When we change `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;` its change the basic behaviour of `callback`. So its not good to change value.

Comment: @IftekharDani It is good to change when needed, with AI, you need to complete the process once the callback is invoked. Otherwise AI will keep busy with the event loop.